# $\mathbb{Z}_2$-cohomology of oriented infinite Grassmannian

Tags: homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes, grassmannian

I know $H^*(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty});\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2[w_1,...,w_n]$ where $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ is the Grassmannian manifold of all $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, $w_i$ is the i-th Stiefel-Whitney class for the universal bundle $\gamma^n$.

I would appreciate it if anyone can tell me what is $H^*(\tilde{G_n}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty});\mathbb{Z}_2)$, where $\tilde{G_n}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ is the oriented Grassmannian, and most preferably provide me a reference or a way to infer this from the knowledge of $H^*(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty});\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the book Characteristic Classes by
John Milnor & James D. Stasheff (which you can find under the following [link](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjo9qnE2s7QAhXEiCwKHThEDIoQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.448.869%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNH0v0YnYklCAav5NWaSCKoRW3dgdA)).

In Theorem 12.4 (on page 146) they use the Gysin sequence (introduced some pages earlier) to conclude that
$$H^*(\tilde{G_n}(\mathbb{R}^\infty); \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[w_2(\tilde{\gamma^n}), \ldots, w_n(\tilde{\gamma^n})]$$
where $\tilde{\gamma^n}$ is the oriented universal bundle on the oriented Grassmannian $\tilde{G_n}(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$.